Unable to import pipeline with crewai
I am unable to import pipeline, I am following exactly as documented in docs.crewai.com I am using python 3.12.4 in virtual environment
from crewai import Pipeline

Import error: cannot import name Pipeline from crewai

How to fix it?

Reinstalling the library on new venv worked.
My approach:

Trying the script on another laptop.(Worked)
Re-installing python on my machine. (I should have created venv instead)

